# Custom modifier in onsen UI

Tags: onsen-ui

I am using Onsen UI in my Cordova project, how is it possible to make custom modifier like `chevron`, `tappable` etc? In documentation it is nothing about this http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#UsingModifier

I want to make theme switcher and load another css files when e.g. `modifier="orange"` or `modifier="blue"`. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining custom modifiers is quite easy. A modifier will add a suffix to the base CSS class, i.e. for `<ons-button>` the base class is `.button`, so if you write

```
<ons-button modifier="orange">Orange button</ons-button>
```

the class `.button--orange` will be added. You can style the modified button by using the following CSS:

```
.button--orange {
  background-color: #ffb836;
}
```

See how it's done in this simple example:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/bVwzJL